# Ignoring Failures on VSTest Task

Tags: azure-devops

We have a VSTest task that is getting a few failures, but we'd like to continue the pipeline anyway. Is there a way to ignore failures, like there is on the PublishTestResults task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSTest task has "Continue on error" checkbox under "Control Options".

Enabling this checkbox will allow you to continue the pipeline by ignoring the failures.

if you are using YAML file, for VSTest step, use

continueOnError: true

to ignore the failures.

Comment: You sure that's there?   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest?view=azure-devops

Comment: And Control Options aren't there anymore, and it's not under any of the other areas.

Comment: @Chris. Sorry for the document mis-leading. For why there' no any words under Control option in doc, that's because this is a general configuration for nearly every task. We combine them into one universal part: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/tasks?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#controloptions You can try with Nirmal's suggestion, it should help achieve what you want. If not, just comment here, I would help further:-)

Comment: Ah!   Now that makes sense. Thank you for the answer!